# Angular CLI proxy server changing response 404 to 200

Tags: angular, playframework, proxy, angular-cli

I have enabled Angular/CLI proxy to proxy my request to rest server( PlayFramework on port 9000). I'm starting my proxy server with

```
ng serve --open --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0
```

This is configuration

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:9000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "bypass": function (req) {
      if (req.headers.accept.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
        console.log("Skipping proxy for browser request.");
        return "/index.html";
      }
    }
  }
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I'm not able to get 404 answer from Play server instead i keep getting OK 200 for unknown routes. It is important to get 404 as PlayServer responds with 404 if user is not authorized to get some route. When using Postman this looks something like this 
when running

```
http://localhost:9000/api/secured
```

i get 404 and it's ok

when running

```
http://localhost:4200/api/secured
```

i get 200 and it serves home route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out, my mistake. I had this in my security trait

```
  private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.FrontendController.index())

  /**
    * Action for authenticated users.
    */
  def IsAuthenticated(f: => User => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username , onUnauthorized) { username =>
```

That was doing redirection :(